# Something kills Explorer

Tags: windows-10, powershell, windows-explorer, process, daemon

On the PC of my customer (MS Windows 10 pro 21H1 fully updated) there is some process that temporarily kills Explorer (the file manager daemon). As well, Explorer restores itself in few seconds.

How can I track such behaviour in order to catch the killer?

Edit: I only suppose there is an Explorer killing, since I see the typical blank screen for few seconds

Comment: Could be a profile issue or group policy update. How frequent is it and is the computer domain joined?

Comment: mmmh... I don't think it is a domain issue, since it happens randomic (twice a day) also outside the LAN connection. A possible clue is that such customer usually use different VPN clients and web services (neither internal of their firm)

Comment: I've seen this happen with a corrupt windows profile. You should test if this happens with a different user (make a test user if you have to) and rule out if this works. If so, migrate data to that new user.

Comment: It can also be one the very many Explorer shell processes gone wrong. I have seen this before.

Comment: Yep but... How can I track such processes?
P.S.: no corrupt profile, this user is unluky (three subsequent profiles on two different machines)

Comment: For (complicated) shell problems, look at Nirsoft ShellView.

Comment: This blank screen shows only on startup of the windows? or that repeat it self every amount of time ? Try to find somthing with this batch file [Processes_Services_Tasks_Startup.bat](https://pastebin.com/ZvWS1XL6)

Comment: One problem is that if explorer is crashing rather than getting killed (more likely if it's restarting), then any investigation will only show explorer killing itself. That said, I would check through the windows event logs around the time of the explorer resets and see if anything useful is getting logged about it.

Answer (score 0):

Here there is my initial and naive approach to such issue:

[Hunter.ps1](https://github.com/dcorrada/POWERSHELL/blob/tempus/Hunter.ps1)

> This script monitors for all the PIDs which belong to a named process.
> Whenever any PID die, this script take a snapshot of the processes list before and after the killing event (into two csv files).

**Acknowledgements** *I am in debt of gratitude with @Hackoo and its inspiring [batch script](https://pastebin.com/ZvWS1XL6)*

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).